# Issue in using bootstrap datetime picker with bootstrap 3.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm new in using bootstrap, I want to use [**Thiago de Arruda's** plugin for datetimepicker](https://github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker) in my app, but it is using bootstrap-2.2 version (bootstrap.2.2 JS and bootstrap-combined.2.2.css) and my app is using Ver 3.3 bootstrap.

When I used latest bootstrap libraries(Ver3.3) ; plugin is not working and not rendering calender view just displaying an empty input box.

[image: Bootstrap issue in datetime picker]

When I tried with new bootstrap.3.3.js & bootstrap-combined.2.2.css it partially working.

I know [Bootstrap 3 Migration Guide](http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide#migration) need to apply for upgradation but it will be huge task for me.

Does any one knows how to fix it? or any references?

Thanks in advance .. :)

Comment: Why not using a bootstrap 3 capable datetime picker?

Comment: Its an improved version,Look [here](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).  I need a date-time picker looks like http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/ -- it only provides date picker.

Comment: What's wrong with [this](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) one ?

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply Mr. sb9 . I think it cannot be inline/embedded only it can be a component;  no "Before-show-day callback" like in http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/. Plz correct me If my assumptions are wrong.